# json encode with changing column names, that api can understand

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json, api

previously I have been using

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

 $data[] = $row;
}
$json = array("status"=>"success","msg"=>"DisplaySuccessfully","data"=>$data);
}
```

//this is the code i used to send data to api which worked fine.

but now I need to bring change in column name so that api functions wont collide. Because same table is being used in 2 api. 
I need to change the column name in such a way that api cannot distinguish column_name and column_data.
//I tried the code below but api can distinguish column_name and data

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
foreach ($row as $key => $val)
    {
        $data[] = $key.'1:'.$val;
    }

 }
$json = array("status"=>"success","msg"=>"Display Successfully","data"=>$data);
}
```

Thank you...

Comment: What you're doing is just changing the column values, not column names, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `mysql_fetch_array` is deprecated and unsafe to use. You need to upgrade to `PDO` or `mysqli`.

And the results of this two are not the same because in first example you have in `$data` an entry for each row, but in second one you have an entry for each value of each row. So to change second example and to get only the values you will need to change the `foreach` like this

```
$data_row = []; //first init the data for one row
foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
    $data_row[] = $val;   // Add the value to the $data_row
}
$data[] = $data_row; //Add the row with values to the $data.
```